# How populate mysql group_cat into table

Tags: php, mysql

Using this mysql statement: `"select group_concat(brand_name) as names, group_concat(order_qty) as qty, vendor, recpt_date, order_recpt from emr_drugs_order group by order_recpt, recpt_date` "

```
names                qty        vendor      recpt_date  order_recpt 
pep coke, hans fruit     100,20          XYZ            2013-12-01       001
light                    23              QRST           2013-12-01       002
```

i get the required results but i want to split them into a table like by grouping them into date and order_recpt :

How do i display the results into a HTML table like this :

```
Date       | Order Recpt | Vendor | Names       | Qty
2013-12-01   001            XYZ
                                   Pep Coke       100         
                                   Hans Fruit     20
2013-12-01   002            QRST
                                   Light          23
```

Comment: Use [`echo`](http://php.net/echo), or other output command.

Comment: Yes i know i have to use echo but how do i use the echo with while statement to populate it into the table

Comment: You want to insert result to some other table ?

Comment: Do not store the basket in one row.  Better use a One to Many relationship,  One ticket or basket has many items.

Comment: Even if i use one to many relationship, how do i group them and display the sub items

Comment: What do you mean _populate in a table_? Are you trying to perform an insert into a MySQL table? If so, your table example doesn't look correct - what are those blanks?

Comment: I want to display the results into a table by grouping them into date, order recpt and vendor

Comment: I think OP wants to generate an HTML table.

Comment: Are you asking how to write PHP to run a sql command, then use that result set to populate an HTML table?

Comment: Why not simple use `str_replace(',', '<br>', $var)` to print the linebreak instead of the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're wanting to generate an HTML table, not a MySQL table. Something like this should get you started: http://www.sudobash.net/web-dev-populate-phphtml-table-from-mysql-database/

Comment: Thanks so much i was able to display it at least in a format table.